# datadog manual injection, tracer scope active always null

Tags: node.js, datadog, fastify

I'm trying to add basic logging info for my datadog account following example as shown on this link but nothing is showing as request to tracer.scope().active() returns null.

https://docs.datadoghq.com/tracing/other_telemetry/connect_logs_and_traces/nodejs/

logger.ts

```
import tracer from "dd-trace";
import formats from "dd-trace/ext/formats";

class Logger {
  log(level: string, message: string): void {
    const span = tracer.scope().active();
    const time = new Date().toISOString();
    const record = { time, level, message };

    if (span) {
      tracer.inject(span.context(), formats.LOG, record);
    }

    console.log(JSON.stringify(record));
  }
}

export default Logger;
```

Plus using standard approach to add datadog to my server.

tracer.ts

```
import tracer from "dd-trace";

tracer.init();

export default tracer;
```

with datadog environment variables set as follows:

```
DD_SERVICE=my-service
DD_AGENT_HOST='<my agent host>'
DD_ENV='dev'
DD_LOGS_INJECTION='true'
DD_PROFILING_ENABLED='true'
DD_TRACE_SAMPLE_RATE='1'
DD_VERSION='1.0.0'
```

server.ts

```
import { FastifyInstance } from "fastify";
import "./tracer";
...
other stuff
```

When I then use Logger, for example as follows:

```
import Logger from "logger";
const logger = new Logger();
logger.log("info", "test message");
```

... the message is never logged on datadog as the request to tracer.scope().active() always returns null.

I know the basic setup is working as when I start up my server I can see the DATADOG TRACER CONFIGURATION setup messages plus when I look on datadog I can see the service is active under APM services/traces, so what piece of the jigsaw am I missing?

Versions:
dd-trace: 1.7.1 (using this version to avoid breaking change/clash with another library).
node: 18.
fastify: 4.2.0.

Thanks in advance for any help with this.

Noel

Comment: you really should use Fastify logger, and now create a new logger all the time, see this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/DataDog/dd-trace-js/issues/1859), it has a setup that is actually working